# TPU utilization low due to output fusion

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I am training a U-Net on a Google Cloud TPU. It works but the utilization is very low.

Due to the fact I can not upload the traced profile here (?), a screenshot of the most slowing part is here:
[image: tpu_utilization]

The output fusion is the most harming part. with 58% of time but just 12% utilization. The next time consuming part (9%) is "convolution" with a utilization of 74%. I am not really sure which operations I need to tweak to get a better utilization of the output fusion?

Below is my code for creating the U-Net, maybe there is a slow layer inside?:

```
class UNet:
def create(self, input, start_ch, depth, inc_rate,
           dropout, batchnorm, maxpool, upconv, residual, leaky_relu_alpha):
    with tf.variable_scope('Generator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        o = self._level_block(input, start_ch, depth, inc_rate, dropout, batchnorm, maxpool, upconv, residual,
                              leaky_relu_alpha)
        out_ch = input.shape[3]
        o = tf.layers.conv2d(o, out_ch, 1)
        o = tf.tanh(o)
        return o

def _conv_block(self, m, dim, bn, res, leaky_relu_alpha, do=0):
    n = tf.layers.conv2d(m, dim, 3, padding='same')
    n = tf.nn.leaky_relu(n, alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)
    n = tf.layers.batch_normalization(n) if bn else n
    n = tf.layers.dropout(n, do) if do else n
    n = tf.layers.conv2d(n, dim, 3, padding='same')
    n = tf.nn.leaky_relu(n, alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)
    n = tf.layers.batch_normalization(n)if bn else n
    return tf.concat([m, n], axis=-1) if res else n

def _level_block(self, m, dim, depth, inc, do, bn, mp, up, res, leaky_relu_alpha):
    if depth > 0:
        n = self._conv_block(m, dim, bn, res, leaky_relu_alpha)
        m = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(n, [2, 2], [2, 2]) if mp else tf.layers.conv2d(n, dim, 3, strides=2, padding='same')
        m = self._level_block(m, int(inc * dim), depth - 1, inc, do, bn, mp, up, res, leaky_relu_alpha)
        if up:
            m = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(m, (2*m.shape[1], 2*m.shape[2]))
            m = tf.layers.conv2d(m, dim, 2, padding='same')
            m = tf.nn.leaky_relu(m, alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)
        else:
            m = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(m, dim, 3, strides=2, padding='same')
            m = tf.nn.leaky_relu(m, alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)

        n = tf.concat([n, m], axis=-1)
        m = self._conv_block(n, dim, bn, res, leaky_relu_alpha)
    else:
        m = self._conv_block(m, dim, bn, res, leaky_relu_alpha, do)
    return m
```

My input batch size is 128. U-Net depth is 4. Using no BatchNorm layers (batchnorm=False), conv2d_transpose (upconv=False), residual=False and maxpool=True. So U-Net consists just of Conv2D, Conv2D_Transpose, Dropout, Leaky ReLU, Max Pooling and Concatenation Layers.

Any Idea what I need to tweak to get a better "output fusion" utilization? Or at least what does affect the output fusion?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the convolution.114 has a lot of padding, 16*1 out of 128*8. Since your global batch size is 128, the local batch size for each core is only 16 (128/8). Would it be possible for you to increase the batch size of your model to 1024?

Comment: If I go higher than 128 with batch size, I get memory exhausted errors. Do you think it is correlated with too small batches? Do you know what is actually meant by "output fusion"?

Comment: Output fusion means any elementwise operations fused with a convolution or matmul (matmuls are lowered into convolutions now, so it's always a convolution). Note that it's irrelevant whether the elementwise ops are fused into the convolution LHS input, RHS input or output - it's always output fusion.  output fusion is good. Having lots of it in your HLO profile shows the compiler is doing Good Things. For the memory exhausted error, you can use the memory_viewer tool to see how much the padding is and optimize on that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But why is the utilization so bad on that "good" fusion?
BTW I reduced my input dimensions to 128x128 images and thus can increase the batch size to 1024. The utilization increased to overall utilization of about 33%, for the output fusion too. Nevertheless this is still not as good as I expected.

Comment: The flops utilization is normalized to the peak FLOPS of TPU matrix multiplication unit. In your output fusion, there are many element wise operations with low FLOPs, e.g. broadcast and constants. These lowered the average FLOPS utilization.  If you look at the FLOPS of individual convolution ops that are not fused, those are usually high.